# Asymptotic behavior of function in terms of constants

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, computer-science

I'm interested in understanding the behavior of the limit

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n\alpha^{c \ln n}
$$

where $\alpha \ge 1$ and $c < 0$.

I'm particularly interested in understanding the relationship between $\alpha$ and $c$ such that this limit approaches a positive constant, $p \in [0,1]$. I believe such a relationship should exist since this limit represents a bound on a probability from a problem in communication complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider

$$ n\alpha^{c \ln n}=e^{\ln n+c\ln n\ln \alpha}$$

with

$$\ln n+c\ln n\ln \alpha=\ln n \left(1+c\ln \alpha\right)$$